# How to extract the number from a string using Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string as follows:  `first, last (123456)` the expected result should be `123456`. Could someone help me in which direction should I proceed using Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambiguous and needs clarification. Based on your comment it appears you want to select the six digits after the left bracket. You can use the Oracle `instr` function to find the position of a character in a string, and then feed that into the `substr` to select your text.

```
select substr(mycol, instr(mycol, '(') + 1, 6) from mytable
```

Or if there are a varying number of digits between the brackets:

```
select substr(mycol, instr(mycol, '(') + 1, instr(mycol, ')') - instr(mycol, '(') - 1) from mytable
```

Comment: This is just an example the length of the string can vary i.e it can also be firstname,lastname (1234556)

Comment: Answer updated. Please reword your questions to specify exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on the actual pattern you care about (I assume "first" and "last" aren't literal hard-coded strings), but you will probably want to use [regexp_substr](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm).

For example, this matches anything between two brackets (which will work for your example), but you might need more sophisticated criteria if your actual examples have multiple brackets or something.

```
SELECT regexp_substr(COLUMN_NAME, '\(([^\)]*)\)', 1, 1, 'i', 1)
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the last `(` and get the sub-string after without the trailing `)` and convert that to a number:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2261/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test ( str ) AS
SELECT 'first, last (123456)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'john, doe (jr) (987654321)' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(
         TRIM(
           TRAILING ')' FROM
           SUBSTR(
             str,
             INSTR( str, '(', -1 ) + 1
           )
         )
       ) AS value
FROM   test
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f2261/1/0)**:

```
|     VALUE |
|-----------|
|    123456 |
| 987654321 |
```